# How to refer a variable inside the argument list of power shell start-process command?

Tags: windows, powershell, automated-tests, start-process

this is a relatively simple script. I am passing some parameters to a script as variables and I want to use them in the start-process command. So I need to refer to the variables in the argument list of start-process command.
Here are the parameters of the script,

```
param(
[string]$installer,  
[string]$location,   
[string]$mode,       
[string]$components, 
[string]$svnhost,    
[string]$destination 
)
```

Here is the start-prcoess command,

```
Start-Process $destination -ArgumentList '/silent /acceptLicense=yes /silent /COMPONENTS="$components" /svnaddress="$svnhost" /svnport="8085"' -Wait
```

The problem is the variables `$components` and `$svnhost` never refer to their actual value. When I run the script, they always get passed as strings i.e.  `$components` and `$svnhost` inside powershell. Does anyone know how do I pass them inside the argument list so that they refer to their actual value?

Comment: Are you sure the the `$components`, `$svnhost` and `svnport` need quotes around them? The single quotes around the ArgumentList string prevent the variables from being expanded. Use double-quotes and backticks to escape the quotes inside as in `Start-Process $destination -ArgumentList "/silent /acceptLicense=yes /silent /COMPONENTS=\`"$components\`" /svnaddress=\`"$svnhost\`" /svnport=\`"8085\`"" -Wait`

Comment: I had solved it, they dont need the quotes around them. Just needed to use the double quotes in the -ArgumentList value.